# Intersection of a small Riemannian sphere and a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $N$ is a closed submanifold in a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$. For $q \in M \setminus N$, consider the sphere $$S = S\big(q, d(q,N)\big) = \{x \in M | d(q, x) = d(q, N)\},$$
where $d(q,N) = \min \{d(q, y) | y \in N\}$ is the distance from $q$ to $N$. Clearly, $S \cap N$ consists of precisely those points of $N$ where the distance $d(q,N)$ is attained.

Now, it seems very intuitive to me that if $d(q, N)$ is sufficiently small, the intersection is a singleton. My reasoning is that for $d(q,N)$ sufficiently small, the sphere is "too much curved", compared to the (compact) submanifold $N$, which makes sure that the sphere can only "touch" $N$ at a single point.

Is my reasoning remotely correct? If so, could someone please point out how to make this rigorous, or maybe point to any reference?

Thanks in advance. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: I overdid it. As @ChesterX points out, it's much simpler than that. For each $p \in N$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\exp_N$ is a diffeomorphism on a neighborhood of $(p,0)\in \Sigma^\epsilon$. By the compactness of $N$, there is a uniform $\epsilon$ such that $\exp_N$ is a diffeomorphism on $\Sigma^\epsilon$.

The longwinded discussion below is how to get a lower bound on $\epsilon$ in terms of the second fundamental form of $N$ and the Riemann curvature of $M$.

This is true, but the proof is somewhat involved. The first observation is that if a geodesic from $N$ to $q$ is minimal, then the geodesic is orthogonal to $N$. For each $p \in N$, let $\Sigma^\epsilon_p \subset T_pM$ be the set of tangent vectors orthogonal to $T_pN$ with length less than $\epsilon$. Let $$\Sigma^\epsilon = \cup_{p\in N} \Sigma^\epsilon_p.$$ Define the map
\begin{align*}
\exp_N: \Sigma^\epsilon &\rightarrow M\\
v &\mapsto \exp_p v\text{ for each }v \in \Sigma^\epsilon_p.
\end{align*}
It now suffices to show that for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, this map is a diffeomorphism. The proof necessarily involves the second fundamental form of $N$ and the curvature of $M$, for exactly the reason you give.

The rest of the proof involves first gettng a lower bound for $\epsilon$ such that that $\exp_N$ is a diffeomorphism in a neighborhood in $\Sigma^\epsilon$ of $p \in N$. I suggest trying to work out the proof when $M$ is Eulicdean space.

In general, this involves estimating the differential of $\exp_N$, most easily done using Jacobi fields. The second fundamental form of $N$ and the sectional curvature of $M$ appear when analyzing the Jacobi equation. Compactness of $N$ then implies a uniform lower bound of $\epsilon$ for every $p \in N$.

I don't know if there is a differential geometry book that works this all out, but a paper that addresses this is a classic one by Heintze and Karcher.

Comment: I believe I have seen the same statement elsewhere (maybe in the Sakai book?) in a different form : the normal exponential map $\exp_N$ is a diffeomorphism before the tangent cut time. But with this, we no longer need any condition on curvature right? With the $\epsilon$ as above, it seems to me just taking $d(q, N) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ will do, no matter the curvature.

Comment: @ChesterX, yes. That sounds right.